# different results using R in windows and linux

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu-12.04, k-means

I have a problem using kmeans in a ubuntu system. I seem to be getting different results! 
My data is say:

```
x<- c(0.1295..,-0.58928,-0.244252,-0.41614,-0.58804,-0.74628,-0.9045188,-1.050903,-1.197288,-1.3353877,-1.47348656,-1.607894)
```

when I perform kmeans function and want to get only the max value of kmeans$centers in a windows system,

```
means <- max(kmeans(x, 3)$centers)
means
[1] -0.05892
```

When I run the exact code in ubuntu 12.04 system, I get a completely different answer

```
means <- max(kmeans(x,3)$centers)
means
[1] -0.1482334
```

So, I performed the kmeans again without the max function

```
means <- kmeans(x, 3)
means$centers
NULL
```

But, means itself has all the entries

```
means


Available components:
[1] "cluster" "centers" "tots" "withinss" "tot.withinss"
[6] "betweenss" "size" "iter" "ifault"
```

There seems to be something changing between the functionality in windows and linux. Can anyone help me figuring this out?!

Comment: kmeans starts with random centroids, have you tried adding `set.seed(123)` to the beginning of both scripts?

Comment: Thanks sebastian, that actually did the trick. I think thats the advantage of using RStudio! I was running the code in Rstudio in windows and I guess it did this automatically and I had to set.seed(123) manually in ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A k-means algorithm generally is not deterministic, i.e., it usually does not lead to perfectly reproducible results. The main reason is that in common algorithms the [initialization is random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Initialization_methods).

As discussed in ?kmeans

> trying several random starts (nstart> 1) is often recommended

Comment: Thanks RHertel, This worked as well and as suggested by @sebastian-c, set.seed(123) worked as well. Now, I have to try to run this using rollapply and see if I get the results as I got with RStudio in windows.

Comment: I'm glad that your question was answered and that I could contribute to it. I would just like to add that you may obtain the same result on different machines by using `set.seed()`, but this does not mean that this same result is better than what you obtained with a different pseudo-random seed, or without specifying any seed.

Comment: I understand the point you make here. I am trying to replicate the results I got on the first machine since they are tested results and I am rewriting a code on linux to be able to publish and run on a server. But I will surely keep that in mind. thanks again!